# What is the the derivative of inverse skew-symetric matrix $\frac{\partial( W^{-1})}{\partial \omega_i}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

What is the the derivative of inverse skew-symetric matrix $\frac{\partial (W^{-1})}{\partial \omega_i}$  where $W=[\omega]_\times$,  $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\omega_i$ is the $i$-th element of $\omega$;  $[\omega]_\times=\begin{bmatrix}0&-\omega_3&\omega_2\\
\omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1\\
-\omega_2 &\omega_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

The wiki page on [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives) about **Identites in differential form** says:
$$
d(X^{-1})=-X^{-1}dXX^{-1}
$$

Is it correct to say that:
$$
\frac{\partial (W^{-1})}{\partial \omega_i}=-W^{-1}\frac{\partial (W)}{\partial \omega_i}W^{-1}=-W^{-1}[e_i]_\times W^{-1},
$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$-th column of an identity matrix of $3\times3$.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. For anyone not familiar with the $[\omega]_\times$ notation, you should state that $$W=\sum_{i=1}^3 \omega_i\,[e_i]_\times$$

Comment: Hi, I just realise the [odd skew-symmetric matrix cannot be invertible](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/if-a-is-an-invertible-skew-symmetric-matrix-then-prove-a-1-is-also-skew). :(